# How to fix this Http Post file upload error

Tags: c#, .net

I can't post car and can't find the error. When I tried to post car with `frombody` and I didn't have files included yet it worked just fine since I turned it into `fromform` with file it doesn't work and cant even find the error, would be happy if I could find some help, there is all the code I can provide for you to look at:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Car>> PostCar([FromForm] CarApiInputModel carApiInputModel)
{
    try
    {
        // Map properties from input model to the car entity
        var car = new Car
        {
            FirstRegistration = carApiInputModel.FirstRegistration,
            EnginePower = carApiInputModel.EnginePower,
            Price = carApiInputModel.Price,
            Features = carApiInputModel.Features,
            Description = carApiInputModel.Description,
            Location = carApiInputModel.Location,
            CarBrandId = carApiInputModel.CarBrandId,
            CarModelId = carApiInputModel.CarModelId,
            CarFuelTypeId = carApiInputModel.CarFuelTypeId,
            CarColorId = carApiInputModel.CarColorId,
            CarConditionId = carApiInputModel.CarConditionId,
            CarMileageId = carApiInputModel.CarMileageId,
            CarSeatsId = carApiInputModel.CarSeatsId,
            CarTransmissionTypeId = carApiInputModel.CarTransmissionTypeId,
            CarVersionId = carApiInputModel.CarVersionId,
            Photos = new List<CarPhoto>()
        };

        // Fetch related entities from the database based on IDs
        car.CarBrand = await _context.Brands.FindAsync(car.CarBrandId);
        car.CarModel = await _context.Models.FindAsync(car.CarModelId);
        car.CarFuelType = await _context.FuelTypes.FindAsync(car.CarFuelTypeId);
        car.CarColor = await _context.Colors.FindAsync(car.CarColorId);
        car.CarCondition = await _context.Condition.FindAsync(car.CarConditionId);
        car.CarMileage = await _context.Mileages.FindAsync(car.CarMileageId);
        car.CarSeats = await _context.Seats.FindAsync(car.CarSeatsId);
        car.CarTransmissionType = await _context.TransmissionTypes.FindAsync(car.CarTransmissionTypeId);
        car.CarVersion = await _context.Versions.FindAsync(car.CarVersionId);

        // Check if any of the entities is not found
        if (car.CarBrand == null || car.CarModel == null || car.CarFuelType == null || car.CarColor == null ||
            car.CarCondition == null || car.CarMileage == null || car.CarSeats == null ||
            car.CarTransmissionType == null || car.CarVersion == null)
        {
            return NotFound("One or more related entities not found.");
        }

        foreach (var file in carApiInputModel.Photos)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Read the file content into a MemoryStream
                    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);

                    // Create a new CarPhoto entity for each file
                    var carPhoto = new CarPhoto
                    {
                        PhotoData = ms.ToArray(),
                        ContentType = file.ContentType
                        // Set other properties as needed (e.g., caption, description, etc.)
                    };

                    // Associate the CarPhoto with the Car
                    car.Photos.Add(carPhoto);
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the Car entity with the associated CarPhotos
        _context.Cars.Add(car);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("Getcar", new { id = car.Id }, car);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

```
namespace AutoMarket.Models
{
    public class CarApiInputModel
    {
        public DateTime FirstRegistration { get; set; }
        public int EnginePower { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public string Features { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int CarBrandId { get; set; }
        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public int CarFuelTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CarColorId { get; set; }
        public int CarConditionId { get; set; }
        public int CarMileageId { get; set; }
        public int CarSeatsId { get; set; }
        public int CarTransmissionTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CarVersionId { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> Photos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is the AutoMarket Model

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AutoMarket.Models
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstRegistration { get; set; }

        public int EnginePower { get; set; } 

        public float Price { get; set; }


        public string Features { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int CarBrandId { get; set; }
        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public int CarFuelTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CarColorId { get; set; }
        public int CarConditionId { get; set; }
        public int CarMileageId { get; set; }
        public int CarSeatsId { get; set; }
        public int CarTransmissionTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CarVersionId { get; set; }


        public IdentityUser User { get; set; }

        public CarBrand CarBrand { get; set; }
        public CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
        public CarCondition CarCondition { get; set; }
        public CarColor CarColor { get; set; }
        public CarFuelType CarFuelType { get; set; }  
        public CarMileage CarMileage { get; set; }
        public CarSeats CarSeats { get; set; }
        public CarTransmissionType CarTransmissionType { get; set; }
        public CarVersion CarVersion { get; set; }
        public List<CarPhoto> Photos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is the CarPhote Model

```
namespace AutoMarket.Models 
{ 
   public class CarPhoto 
   { 
      public int Id { get; set; } 
      public byte[] PhotoData { get; set; } 
      public string ContentType { get; set; } 
      public int CarId { get; set; } 
      public Car Car { get; set; } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: namespace AutoMarket.Models
{
    public class CarPhoto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoData { get; set; }  
        public string ContentType { get; set; } 
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
}
this is my carphoto model too

Comment: Please update the question with a specific error that you are facing. [*It's not working*](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not sufficient.